# Image Region Swapping in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, image-manipulation

This is my first time developing an J2ME application.
I am trying to swap the regions in an image.
I am allowing the users to tap 2 image region in a image.
Rectangles will be drawn to show the region. 
I just need to know how to swap them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To Swap Images Follow below steps:

Step 1: Download this class [SlidingImage.java](http://www.jappit.com/uploads/src/SimpleSlidingCanvas.java)

Step 2: Instantiate a new SlidingImage:

```
SlidingImage image = new SlidingImage(
    Image.createImage("/image1.png"),
    10,
    SlidingImage.SLIDE_OUT);
```

These are the constructor arguments:

- An Image object to be slided
- The number of pieces of the sliding image
- The type of slide, can be SlidingImage.SLIDE_IN or
  SlidingImage.SLIDE_OUT

Step 3: Start the sliding effect, specifying its direction and duration (in milliseconds):

```
image.slide(Canvas.RIGHT, 3000);
```

Direction can be one of Canvas properties UP, RIGHT, DOWN and LEFT.

Step 4: Now you can paint it simply specifying coordinates and an anchor, as usual:

```
image.paint(g,100, 100, Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER);
```

Step 5: If you remember ExplodingImage class, you can check if effect is ended with the public ended property:

```
if(image.ended)
{
//effect-end related code
}
```

Step 6: If you want to reset the effect, also changing the sliding image pieces and effect type (slide in or out), you can use the reset() method:

```
//to reset changing also slides and type properties
image.reset(12, SlidingImage.SLIDE_IN);
//otherwise, to simply reset:
image.reset();
```

[Canvas Example](http://www.jappit.com/uploads/src/SimpleSlidingCanvas.java)

Comment: It only teaches you how to slide the images. I wanna get 1 part of the same image and move it around the image. Which also means only 1 image.